# how to get a total value of a property inside a array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the total amount of a certain property in a array. If I get the length of the array with something like this

```
$scope.CustomerCitiesTotalLength= function () {
    $scope.CustomerCities.length;
};
```

How can I get the total amount of this? I need to get the total number of "Houston" and "Dallas" in the array of CustomerCities.

```
CustomerCities,
oject1: "City":"Houston",
object2: "City": "Dallas",
object3: "City": "Dallas",
```

I need to display this info in a pie chart. so the total amount would be, Houston == 1, Dallas == 2

Comment: do it using javascript

Comment: Can you show me how it is done

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredArr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.CustomerCities, function(value, key) {
     if(typeof filteredArr[value.City] != 'undefined') {
         filteredArr[value.City] = filteredArr[value.City]++;
     } else {
         filteredArr[value.City] = 1;
     }
});
```